# How to read a .bsq file in Flink?

Tags: java, apache-flink

After correctly setting up my project I need to read/import several `.bsq` files into my environment. I tried to use the [env.readFile()](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/api/java/ExecutionEnvironment.html#readFile(org.apache.flink.api.common.io.FileInputFormat,%20java.lang.String)) method like this:

```
DataSet<T> data = env.readFile(*insertFileInputFormatHere*, filePath);
```

But I am not able to get a proper `FileInputFormat`. Since it is abstract I can't have my own instance. Should I extend the `abstract class FileInputFormat` and use my own extension to instantiate a `FileInputFormat`? Or is there another way I did not recognize?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that [`.bsq`](http://www.digitalpreservation.gov/formats/fdd/fdd000289.shtml) files are a binary format for which no Flink or Hadoop InputFormat exists (I'm including Hadoop InputFormats because Flink also supports Hadoop IFs)

So you have to implement your own `InputFormat` for reading the file. I would suggest to extend your own InputFormat from Flink's `org.apache.flink.api.common.io.FileInputFormat`.

For using your own input format, you have to call it like

```java
final ExecutionEnvironment env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
env.createInput(new MyInputFormat());
```